# RxSwift equivalent of DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: swift, rx-swift

It seems that rx-swift has not yet implemented [DefaultIfEmpty](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defaultifempty.html). Is there another way I can mimic this behavior?

```
let myList:[Int] = []
myList.toObservable()
    .switchIfEmpty { () in // <- Not (yet?) implemented
        return Observable.of(1)
    }.subscribeNext { num in
        print(num)
    }

// prints 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem but needed only 1 value from observable so simple solution is concatenate and than take 1:

```
yourSingleObservable.concat(Observable.just(defaultValue)).take(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `toArray` to mimic this behavior. An example with `PublishSubject` (can be easily converted to use `myList`, I hope):

```
  let subjectInt = PublishSubject<Int>()
  let emptyReplacement = subjectInt
    .toArray()
    .filter {$0.isEmpty}
    .map{ _ in return 42}

  let defaultIfEmpty = [subjectInt, emptyReplacement].toObservable().merge()

  defaultIfEmpty.subscribeNext {
    print("defaultIfEmpty: \($0)")
  }

  subjectInt.on(.Next(11)) // 
  subjectInt.on(.Next(33)) //comment these 2 lines out to see the default value 42 printed
  subjectInt.on(.Completed)
```

Answer (score 0):

To refine what Michal said, `toArray()` offers a solution:

```
extension Observable {
    func defaultIfEmpty(_ other: Observable<E>) -> Observable<E> {
        let replacement = toArray()
            .flatMap { array -> Observable<E> in
                if array.isEmpty {
                    return other
                } else {
                    return Observable.empty()
                }
            }

        return concat(replacement)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let a = Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
let b = Observable.of(-1, -2, -3)
let c = Observable<Int>.of()

_ = a.defaultIfEmpty(b).subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })

// 1
// 2
// 3

_ = c.defaultIfEmpty(b).subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })

// -1
// -2
// -3
```